# How to get all chemical compounds that interact with a given protein target?

Tags: uniprot, interactions

I want to get all Pubchem Chemical compounds (CID) that interact with a given UniProt target. I have a list of UniProt targets and I need to study the relationship between these targets and chemical compounds.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution to the problem of mapping chemical compounds to protein IDs is to use the ChEMBL compound ID to UniProt [mapping](ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/chembl/ChEMBLdb/releases/chembl_24_1/chembl_uniprot_mapping.txt).

Doing this with PubChem is not so straight forward in part because its downloadable data format is a hideous obfuscated and badly documented mess split over multiple compressed files which in turn contain multiple compressed files...... For a publicly funded project they should really do better.